# React Native: when log out redirect to another stacknavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I use asyncStorage to change login/out state in my application, when I click on logOut I change state to false and then I have to redirect user to another stacknavigation (loginStackNavigation)

```
<TouchableOpacity
style={[styles...]}
onPress={() => onSignOut().then(this.navigateToScreen('LoggingStackNavigation'))}
>
    ...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

ps. onSignOut() function change value stored in asyncstorage

this is navigateToScreen() function:

```
  navigateToScreen = (route) => (
  () => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
    this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
});
```

what can I do to redirect user to `LoggingStackNavigation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a Switch Navigator where you can wrap your 2 navigators:

```
import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

 const routesConfig = {
     NotAuthenticated :{screen: loggedOutStack},
     Authenticated : { screen: loggedInStack}
  }

 const SwitchNavigatorConfig= {
     initialRouteName: "NotAuthenticated"
 }

export const createSwitchNavigator(RoutesConfig, SwitchNavigatorConfigs)
```

Then you can just `navigation.navigate("NotAuthenticated")` when needed

Comment: thank you, I dont use same approach but I used switchNavigation too and its work good now

Comment: Note that using SwitchNavigation will unmount the previous screen/stack when navigating to another one

Answer (score 0):

your function needs to call [navigation.navigate](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html#navigating-to-a-new-screen)

```
navigateToScreen = (route) => (
  () => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
    this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
    this.props.navigation.navigate(route);
});
```

Comment: my fuction works good when I want to navigate to another screen but now I want to navigate to another stacknavigation, when user click on Logout I have to redirect him to another stacknavigation (login - register - .... ) not only one screen, it's already working for this

Comment: You need to provide a fuller example to get that solution. Please accept my answer if I answered your question.

Comment: Its okey I used SwitchNavigation with asyncstorage and it works fine now